# Pandas: Selecting value from preceding row and different column

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I need to make a new dataframe from an existing one. The example below will explain what I mean. For each value in column2 and column3 I need to make a new row that includes the value from column1 that precedes it. I'm not sure how to select that value using pandas.

```
index column1 column2 column3
  0    shop1
  1             34       0
  2             32       0
  3             35       1
  4    shop2
  5             52       1
  6             57       0
```

Resulting dataframe:

```
index column1 column2 column3
  0    shop1    34       0
  1    shop1    32       0
  2    shop1    35       1
  3    shop2    52       1
  4    shop2    57       0
```

I've searched stackoverflow and the pandas documentation, but cannot find how to do this. Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Comment: How about `column1.fillna(method='ffill')` and then removing rows with null values in `column2` or `column3`?

Comment: Damn, that's actually really simple... I can't believe I didn't even think of that. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `ffill()` and `dropna`:

```
df.assign(column1=df.column1.ffill()).dropna()
```

Output:

```
   index column1  column2  column3
1      1   shop1     34.0      0.0
2      2   shop1     32.0      0.0
3      3   shop1     35.0      1.0
5      5   shop2     52.0      1.0
6      6   shop2     57.0      0.0
```

And, if you want to cleanup index:

`df.assign(column1=df.column1.ffill()).dropna().drop('index',1).reset_index(drop=True`)

```
  column1  column2  column3
0   shop1     34.0      0.0
1   shop1     32.0      0.0
2   shop1     35.0      1.0
3   shop2     52.0      1.0
4   shop2     57.0      0.0
```

Answer (score 0):

If those are blanks you would need to make N/A first

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(dict(column1=["shop1","","","shop2",""],column2=["",34,32,"",35]))
df = df.mask(df == '')
df.column1 = df.column1.fillna(method='pad')
df = df.dropna(axis=0,how='any').reset_index(drop=True)

print(df)
```

Returns:

```
  column1 column2
0   shop1      34
1   shop1      32
2   shop2      35
```